# Bootstrap button above table while using div align center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As a backend dev I didnt know how hard frontend was ;).

How can I put the "Create" button above the left side of the table:
[image: The problem]
Right now the button is in the middle of the table because the table is in a . This is the full code:

```
<div align="center">
<h1>All Tournaments </h1>
<p>Show: <a href="/tournaments/?show=played" id="tournament_link">History</a> or <a href="/tournaments/?show=unplayed" id="tournament_link">Unplayed</a></p>
        <a href="create/" class="btn btn-default">Create</a>

<table style="width:50%" id="tournament_table">
<tr id="table_head">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Players needed</th>
    <th>Rounds</th>
    <th>Host</th>
    <th>Select robot</th>
      <th>Played</th>
    <th>Join tournament</th>
```

The button is the  element. I want the page look like this:

[image: The goal]

Thanks

EDIT: The complete page looks like this.

[image: The full page]

The text above and the table beneath the Create button need to be centered. If I pull the button out of the align center div it appears completely to the left.

Comment: Do you want to align the button to left or center ?

Comment: To the left. Like on the second screenshot.

Comment: my answer below should work

Answer (score 0):

Wrap in a div and add class `text-left` on parent as follows:

```
<div align="center" style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto">
    <div class="text-left">
        <h1>All Tournaments </h1>
        <p>Show: <a href="/tournaments/?show=played" id="tournament_link">History</a> or <a href="/tournaments/?show=unplayed" id="tournament_link">Unplayed</a></p>
        <a href="create/" class="btn btn-default">Create</a>
    </div>
    <table id="tournament_table">
       <tr id="table_head">
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Players needed</th>
          <th>Rounds</th>
          <th>Host</th>
          <th>Select robot</th>
          <th>Join tournament</th>
          <th>Played</th>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @gavgrif Sorry I forgot to tell you that there also is text above the button. I updated the question. If I use one of the answers the button appears completely to the left of the screen.

Comment: Thank you but now the button appears completely to the left of the screen. Instead of above the left side of the table.

Comment: @user3302735 - check my amended answer - you neeed to housethe table and the button in a div that is then centered into the page.

Answer (score -1):

Add a class .pull-left to the button

```
<a href="create/" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Create</a>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: sorry SHL - but you have to apply the clearfix class to the parent of the element that houses the float. not the one after. This is becausethe clearfix hack (and it is a hack) applies content of "" after the div - therefore allowing it to be al large as the contained elements.

Comment: @gavgrif please justify your statement. It seems confusing.

Comment: Using this it doesn't break the layout. You can achieve what is expected easily.